# Best way to terminate multiple threads on shutdown

Tags: multithreading, shutdown

I am looking at ways to safely shutdown multiple threads whose job is

```
while(1) {
    doAction
    sleep
}
```

I am considering using a boolean say `is_shutting_down` and let the while loop check for it before going to sleep. However, I am worried that if in sleep, shutdown will have to wait for the sleep to be done before the variable is checked for again. Wondering if there is a way to `wakeup` a sleeping thread and gracefully exit.

Comment: What language, what OS?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET: if there is no cleaning up to be done by the thread: set the IsBackground property of the thread to true and it will terminate with the process.

If there is cleaning up to do I recommend implementing a an explicit call to indeed set a boolean (or a cancellation token when using a Task in .NET) In this case the thread that is closing the process will have to wait for at least the sleep time for the worker thread to wake up and clean up.

I recommend against aborting a thread. Although it might interrupt the thread, if it was doing something at the time of the Abort like writing to a file it might not have completed its work and this could leave state in limbo.